# py2app Not Finding BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, py2app

I have a script that uses [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) that I want to make into a standalone app using [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html).  When I run the app made by py2app I get an error saying that the module BeautifulSoup could not be found.  My sys.path has '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1-py2.6.egg' so it seems like it should be there, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ppy2app doesn't work with python eggs.  You need to extract the contents of the egg (a zip file), or install BeuatifulSoup from a different source.  I Believe BeautifulSoup is 1 source file, so you could just copy it into you app folder.